# Implement a remote command line interface using Ruby/Python

Tags: python, ruby, linux, gitolite

Are there any existing library for implementing a remote command line interface?

e.g.

Consider the case of  `gitolite`, when you do a `git push origin`, it will ssh into the remote server and execute some code (namely `hooks`, no server is needed for the whole transaction.

What I want to archive is something like that, e.g.

```
./remote get_up_time
```

It will invoke ssh into the remote machine and do execute the script `get_up_time` already deployed

Comment: Do you want a complete remote command line or do you only need to be able to execute a single command remotely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `ssh` is installed and that your public key is on the remote server (and thus, you do not need to provide a password), this would be a crude implementation:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

host = ARGV.shift
command = ARGV.join(' ')
IO.popen("ssh #{host} \"#{command}\"") do |io|
  io.sync = true
  io.readlines.each { |line| puts line }
end
```

Usable like:

```
$ ./remote.rb www.example.com ls -l
```

You can expand this as needed to provide extra features, such as reading from stdin to provide `ssh` a password or something.

Although it appears there is "no server", there is certainly an `sshd` (a remote server) running on the remote system that allows this to work.

If you don't want to use `ssh`, you will need to use another server running on the remote machine or write your own.

Answer (score 1):

the ruby standard distribution provides DRb aka Distributed Ruby:

http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/drb/rdoc/DRb.html

Answer (score 1):

Implementing your own script would be easy enough.

```
#!/bin/bash

ssh root@example.com "$1"
```

Then you could just call like:

```
./remote.sh get_up_time
```